# how to prove $\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{|\log x|}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[\epsilon,1]$ for $0<\epsilon <1$ and $\int_0^1 x|f'(x)|^p dx <\infty.$

How to prove $\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{|\log x|}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ if $p=2$?

How to prove $\frac{|f(x)|}{x^{1-2/p}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ if $p<2$?

I don't know how to deal with the condition. I only got that

$f(x)-f(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^x f'(t)dt$,  $|f(x)-f(\epsilon)|\leq\int_\epsilon^x |t^{1/p}f'(t)\cdot t^{-1/p}|dt\leq (\int_\epsilon^x t|f'|^pdt)^{1/p}\cdot (\int_\epsilon^x t^{-q/p})^{1/q} $

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close th the actual solution. The trick is, fix small $0<\epsilon<1$ and notice that for small x, we can write

$$ \int_{x}^{\epsilon} |f'(t)| \, dt = \int_{0}^{1} t^{1/p}|f'(t)| 1_{(0,\epsilon)}(t) \cdot t^{-1/p} 1_{(x,1)}(t) \, dt. $$

Then you can apply the Holder inequality as you tried, which gives you a bound

$$ \limsup_{x\to0+} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} \leq C_{p} \left( \int_{0}^{\epsilon} t|f'(t)|^{p} \right)^{1/p}, $$

where $g(x) = |\log x|^{1/2}$ if $p=2$ and $g(x) = x^{1-2/p}$ if $1<p<2$ and $C_{p} > 0$ is a generic constant depending only on $p$. Therefore taking $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, the claim follows.

Comment: $C_p= (\int_x^1 t^{-q/p})^{1/q}$ depends on $x$ ? When $p\leq 2$,we get $q/p \geq 2$ which indicates $\int_0^1 t^{-q/p}$ is not integrable.

Comment: @user157361, What I implicitly meant was that you get $ \left( \int_{x}^{1} t^{-q/p} \, dt \right)^{1/q} \leq C_{p}g(x) $ for some constant $C_{p} > 0$ which depends only on $p$. (Indeed, you can pick $C_{2} = 1$ and $C_{p} = (\frac{p-1}{2-p})^{1-1/p}$ for $1<p<2$.)

Comment: Yes, I got what you mean. You are right!

Comment: Slight nitpickiness: the integral $\int_{0}^{\epsilon}t\left|f'(t)\right|^{p}$ tends to $0$ as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$ as a consequence of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.